# Docker EE 2.0 - Supported OSes

Tags: docker, rhel, docker-ee

*Note to Moderators:* As this is not a programming question, please delete if it is considered as an inappropriate question for stackoverflow.

I am unable to figure out what are the supported RHEL versions for Docker EE 2.0.

This article ([Compatibility matrix](https://success.docker.com/article/compatibility-matrix)) [image: RHEL versions that are supported] states that RHEL versions 7.3-7.5 are supported.

However the article - [Docker EE end to end Install](https://docs.docker.com/ee/end-to-end-install/) states the following:

Also, make sure the hosts are running one of these operating systems:

- A maintained version of CentOS 7. Archived versions aren’t supported or tested.
- **Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, or 7.3**
  -Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or 16.04 LTS
- SUSE Linux Enterprise 12
- Oracle Linux 7.3

They don't seem to be consistent with each other.

Comment: This is probably more on-topic on ServerFault.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Sources for the [Deploy Enterprise Edition on Linux servers](https://docs.docker.com/ee/end-to-end-install/) page are here:

- https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/ee/end-to-end-install.md

The required base versions were lasted updated in this commit:

> ```
> commit ed842d659d6f903679e5804a7a45e0d79a26b03a
> Author: Joao Fernandes <joao.fernandes@docker.com>
> Date:   Tue Jan 10 16:27:51 2017 -0800
> ```
>
> #### [Adds docs for CSE 1.13-rc1](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/commit/ed842d659d6f903679e5804a7a45e0d79a26b03a)

At this time, Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4 and later versions had not been released yet (7.3 was still current—7.4 went out of the door on August 1st, 2017).  So it seems that the versions in that document simply have not been maintained over time.

Someone has already filed an issue about exactly this issue:

- [Out of date RHEL requirements](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/7066)

Comment: Florian, can you respond to this question on ServerFault at https://serverfault.com/questions/923565/docker-ee-2-0-supported-oses. Once done I will delete this question here on StackOverflow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Created a PR to fix this here: https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/pull/7069

Comment: The question should be closed. Your answer is more appropriate as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I couldn't add a comment to the original question so I made it an answer. https://imgur.com/jfg7r4p